# having a branch for live and development using git on server

Tags: git, ftp, web-deployment

So im fairly new to git and have been using if for a java project i am working on. I also manage the development of a website and want to start using git for that. It seems like there should be a way to do this, but I am not completely sure if it is possible. Anyways, here is what I'm hoping.

1. have a live (branch?) repo that i can push to that stores what is live on the website
2. have a production (branch?) repo that i can push to to view a staged version of the site. This will be contained in a subdirectory of the root of the server.

I read an article on how to make a git server.. but is what i have outlined above possible? I think it would make my life easier rather than having to remember which files i changed to FTP onto my server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any git repo you are pushing to on a server should be a *bare* repo (that way, there is no synchronization issue between what you are pushing and the working tree, since a bare repo has no working tree).

You usually push (the branch you want) to the bare repo, and you have a post-receive hook which will checkout the content of that branch to (one of your) web site directory, depending on the branch you have just pushed.

See "[how to process files on a branch in post-receive hook in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11323004/6309)" as a concrete example.

Comment: With this model is there a way for me to let my clients see the "production branch"? Or something of the sort at least

Comment: @TroyCosentino you can define two separate Git bare repo, each one checkout to a different live website, and give the reference of only the right website (or the right bare git repo) for them to access.

Comment: That makes sense.. And how could I host both of the websites on the same server? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: @TroyCosentino For multiple website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421468/virtualhost-multiple-sites-apache-linux-server.

Answer (score 1):

What your thinking of is having a master branch and a development branch. In general, anything that is pushed to the master branch by convention means that your application should be using that code. When you're pushing to a development branch the code should be small fixes and improvements for your application. Later on these small fixes can be merged into your master branch so your application will be using it.

Comment: right, i understand that much.. but the issue i have is i want to be able to view the development branch, but only by going to a certain URL or something, so that not everyone sees what it looks like.. if that makes sense

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, yes that is possible too. Have a look at an example https://github.com/dillboy928/node-collections/tree/stack This is the branch named stack. It lets you see that branch and all info that goes with it i.e. commit history.

Comment: well, i meant more of if i have index.html in master, and branch and checkout to production. Then i add an image to index.html in production but want to see it online before everyone else can see it online